# How to remove columns from data frame with <3 entries?

Tags: r

I would like to remove all the columns from my data frame that contain less than 3 entries.

Here is an example of the result I would like:

```
A  B  C  D
NA NA NA 1
NA NA 1  2
NA NA 2  3
NA 6  3  4
3  5  4  NA
```

```
C  D
NA 1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  NA
```

I have a dataframe of over 1000 columns, how would I do this for the whole set?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try `df[colSums(!is.na(df)) >= 3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
subset(df,select = colSums(!is.na(df))>=3)
```

which gives

```
   C  D
1 NA  1
2  1  2
3  2  3
4  3  4
5  4 NA
```